# Trying to run scala swing and getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/swing/MainFrame

Tags: scala

Here is my code I am trying to run:

```scala
import scala.swing._

object MyApp extends SimpleSwingApplication{
    def top = new MainFrame{
        contents = new Label("GUI stuff")
    }

}
```

I am running the code through command line. In my directory, I have the code above (`app2.scala`), a scala swing jar file (`scala-swing_2.13-2.1.1.jar`).

I am compiling the scala file like:

```
scalac -cp "scala-swing_2.13-2.1.1.jar" app2.scala
```

then trying to run it through

```
scala MyApp
```

But I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/swing/MainFrame
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:130)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:34)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:70)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:91)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:108)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.swing.MainFrame
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
```

How can I fix this?

I checked that my scala version is the same as the version for swing. I am running 2.13.2

Comment: You need to set the classpath to include the scala swing library for running as well, not just during compilation.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I tried doing so using `scala -cp "scala-swing_2.13-2.1.1.jar" MyApp` and now it returns: `No such file or class on classpath: MyApp`

Comment: You need *both* the library and whatever place holds your MyApp class (probably the local directory) on your classpath: `scala -cp "scala-swing_2.13-2.1.1.jar;." MyApp` (if you're on Linux or MacOS replace the `;` with a `:`).